# Setting minWidth on a BorderLayout center panel?

Tags: extjs, highcharts, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a border layout with a center panel that houses a HighChart. Depending on the number of values loaded into the highchart I want to make the chart/panel width larger or smaller.

Setting minWidth as a static config is great, but then calling setMinWidth() programmatically doesn't seem to update straight away. In fact, if I don't touch the page much then the scrollbars seem to appear around 30 seconds later. Or sometimes not at all.

So question: is there a better way to do this? Should I be setting the width rather than the minWidth?

Things that don't help:
doLayout doesn't seem to be a thing
calling render on the panel causes extJs to complain about duplicate id

Here's a very pared down example of the layout I'm using:

```
Ext.define('Test.view.TestView', {
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  alias: 'widget.mainview',
  id: 'testpanel',
  title: 'Test Page',
  layout: 'border',
  scrollable: 'true',
  initComponent: function () {
    this.items[1] = {
      xtype: 'chart-type',
      region: 'center',
      layout: 'fit',
      bind: {
        stuff: '{things}',
      }
    };
    this.callParent(arguments);
  },
  controller: 'mainview',
  viewModel: 'vm',
  items: [{
    xtype: 'my-form',
    region: 'west'
  }]
});
```

These layout issues are, as always, making me into a crazy person. Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Rather than setting minWidth you can set width.Also which extjs version you use & can you show demo in fiddle ?

Comment: to the point ext complains about duplicate ids, please use itemId instead - because if you add components twice, you will get 2 html components with the same id which is against the spec - using itemIds can prevent that problem - to your problem, i would say it depends on when you know how much items you will add, but may be its better to wrap it again in a component which does not use fit layout - it would be better to get a fiddle from you